# Hot reloading components in Gatsby doesn't work

Tags: javascript, webpack, gatsby

I've started using Gatsby JS and there is something very strange in hot reloading components used. If by any chance you have a 2 level implementation of components, i.e.

```
/components
   /Component
      index.js
      styles.css
```

it seems that hot reloading is not working...

I've tried to flatten my components to be direct child of components folder and it works normally. Does anyone experienced this issue?

Gatsby info

```
System:
    OS: macOS 10.14
    CPU: (4) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-4288U CPU @ 2.60GHz
    Shell: 5.3 - /bin/zsh
  Binaries:
    Node: 11.2.0 - /usr/local/bin/node
    Yarn: 1.10.1 - /usr/local/bin/yarn
    npm: 6.4.1 - /usr/local/bin/npm
  Languages:
    Python: 2.7.14 - /usr/local/bin/python
  Browsers:
    Chrome: 74.0.3729.169
    Firefox: 67.0.1
    Safari: 12.0
  npmPackages:
    gatsby: ^2.9.4 => 2.9.4
    gatsby-background-image: ^0.7.1 => 0.7.1
    gatsby-image: ^2.1.4 => 2.1.4
    gatsby-plugin-manifest: ^2.1.1 => 2.1.1
    gatsby-plugin-offline: ^2.1.3 => 2.1.3
    gatsby-plugin-react-helmet: ^3.0.12 => 3.0.12
    gatsby-plugin-sass: ^2.0.11 => 2.0.11
    gatsby-plugin-sharp: ^2.1.5 => 2.1.5
    gatsby-source-filesystem: ^2.0.39 => 2.0.39
    gatsby-transformer-sharp: ^2.1.21 => 2.1.21
  npmGlobalPackages:
    gatsby-cli: 2.6.7
```

Thank you for your help.